# Article “the“ for superlative

Tags: grammar, articles, comparison

Which one is correct:
“XYZ is the most famous and the biggest concert in Australia.“ or 
“XYZ is the most famous and biggest concert in Australia.“?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to ELL!

The first is strictly correct.

It is the word *most* that causes the problem, I think. The second sentence is slightly awkward as it implies a double superlative: **most biggest**. [Double superlatives](https://www.thoughtco.com/double-superlative-grammar-1690476) are regarded as non-standard nowadays. [Shakespeare often used them however.]

The repeat of *the* in “the most famous and the biggest" avoids the problem, but it might be even better and more idiomatic to say "the biggest and most famous".

Answer (score 0):

Neither are totally wrong, but this is much more idiomatic:

> XYZ is the biggest and most famous concert in Australia.

[This handy chart](https://www.woodwardenglish.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/adjectives-word-order-english-osascomp.jpg) might help you understand adjective order in English.

Duplicating "the" is unnecessary and so usually we omit it.